Signs that someone's kindness is real, and not just virtue signalling
I am looking at Torah lessons that enable one to assess if someone's kindness is genuine and not just a front for the sake of honour.
For example, if they are kind towards homeless people, but not kind to their family, maybe the Torah has something to say about that? (see the intro to Garden of Wisdom)
Do we have any statements of Chazal that help us assess this? For bonus points, practical advice would be also provided, e.g. how to improve one's own (or educate others') situation from being kind only for honour, to being kind lishma

The way this question is worded sounds like there are only two options - either it's genuine or it's just a front.  This is a false dichotomy because much of the time both motivations are present at the same time.

Why does it matter whether kindness is sincere or not, applies to everybody you know or not?  It's action that matters, not intent.   The Talmud [Kiddushin 40a] says:

Evil intention is not combined with deed, [there is no punishment for mere intention], for it is said: "If I saw iniquity in my heart, The Lord would not hear." [Ps. 66:18].  [Evil] intention which bears fruit [i.e., which is followed by action] the Holy One, blessed be He, combines with deed, [punishing both]. [Evil] intention which does not bear fruit the Holy One, blessed be He, does not combine with deed [and there is therefore no punishment].

Here there is not even evil intention, only incompletely good intention, so this applies in spades.  Partial observance, or observance for the wrong reasons, is always better than no observance at all.

I am normally against undermining the premise of a question but in this case it is such a great point +1

Aren't we supposed to regard others l'kaf zechut anyway? Assume they're sincere and it will go well :)

I don't believe there is any way to truly assess if someone's kindness is true and not for the sake of honor. Only Moshiach will be able to judge a person's true essence, and not be fooled by the senses (Yeshayahu 11:3) and of the seven things that are hidden from man's knowledge, one is what is in the heart of another (Bereishis Rabbah 65:12). However, not only are we unable to tell the intents behind someone's kindness, the Talmud seems to have many anecdotes that would appeal to those who do kindness Lo-Lishmah, speaking on matters of Olam Haba and Gehinnom, informing the reader how they will be rewarded with certain kindnesses. This information would not appeal to someone who does good deeds for no reward and want to do mitzvot simply Lishmah. It would seem that the Talmud wants as many readers as possible to add as much kindness as possible to the world, and is not bothered by intent. As Arachin 16b says:

A person should always engage in Torah and mitzvot even Lo-Lishmah, as through Lo-Lishmah, one will come to do them Lishmah.

Comparing intentions vs actions, the Nefesh HaChaim concludes "the essential part of all Mitzvot are the details of their physical performance" (Shaar 1, Perek 22) and that "purity of thought only complements the act of the mitzvah" (Perakim, Perek 5). Furthermore, one should not not chide a lifelong learner who is clearly doing it for their own prestige, because there is an assumption they had a moment of Lishmah within a learning session, and those tiny moments within each session elevated all their learning (Perakim, Perek 4). While the Nefesh HaChaim refers only to learning Torah in that instance, perhaps we can apply this also to mitzvot (see below, second to last paragraph).
In terms of how to improve and do kindness Lishmah, the best antidote is as mentioned above, to do many kindnesses Lo-Lishmah, because it will bring you to Lishmah. For example, it is better to give money to the homeless painfully than not at all. If one keeps doing it, it goes from painful to a habit. If they keep at it, it goes from a habit to a joy, and then to a highlight of the day. Another powerful antidote is daily Torah learning. As Kiddishim 30b says:

I created the yezter hara and I created for it the Torah as an antidote, and if you busy yourself with Torah you will not be delivered into its hand

Related, Midrash Tehillim 1:15:

Rabbi Eliezer says, "The people of Israel said before the Holy One, blessed be He, Master of the Universe, we want to engage in Torah day and night, but we have no free time." The Holy One, blessed be He, said to them, "Perform the mitzvah of tefillin, and I will consider it as if you were engaged in Torah day and night."

Not to deviate too far from the subject, but one of the reasons why Tefillin has this ability is because it has the power to transform mitzvot done Lo-Lishmah to Lishmah. Here is the explanation of that idea.
The big barrier to doing kindness Lishmah is the Yetzar Hara. The Yetzar Hara is the ego and its drive towards honor (Bereishis Rabbah 9:7). As a result, the best remedy is to cultivate humility. Advice on how to cultivate humility is found in Rebbe Nachman's Likutei Etzot, Iggeret HaRamban, Rabbi Sacks has a fantastic article on humility, Mesilas Yesharim is on how to attain humility, Chovot HaLevavot has an excellent chapter on it, and there is much more. Thank you for your time, and thank you for your excellent question.

And thank you for your excellent answer +1

Also for your second paragraph's question, this didn't fully fit the requirements for an answer, so I'll say as a comment: Rabbi Y Y Jacobson has a great video on chizzuk for people that do kindness for others but overlook their family: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NO_y7Zc9kYk&ab_channel=RabbiYYJacobson

Thanks v much. Given your interest in Chassidus, I'ld be glad for any info you have on how to tell if I, myself, am being truly kind, or doing it for selfish reasons. I already liked where you are going with bittul. Considering making it into its own question

Another thing for your second paragraph, comparing kindness towards your family to kindness towards the homeless, I know a Torah idea offhand, but can't source it so I didn't include it in the main question: kindness to your family is more difficult than kindness towards others. It's easy to have an abstract love for other people you never met, but when you're close to them and interact, it's difficult. That's why the Torah says "love your neighbor" rather than "love all Jews" -- loving "all Jews" as an abstract is easy, but loving the person in front of me might take effort.

@Rabbi Kaii I don't know if there is any way to know 100% for sure, "don't trust yourself until your day of death," but running away from honor might be a good measure. See if you still want to do those kindnesses even if you get no credit. If you still do mitzvot with lots of love -- great news! Also I recommend to incorporate additional self-examinations (hitbodidot). Also, Tomar Devorah end of Ch 2 (Midat HaKeter) has 5 pieces of advice to rid arrogance and selfishness that I find fantastic. Sefaria's translation is pretty good, but I don't know if it fully captures the Ramak's wisdom.

Yes, I also was moved by the Ramak's advice, glad to know someone else was too
